# How do I update my Angular $scope variable based off of a global variable in another non Angular JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How do I update my Angular $scope variable based off of a global variable in another non JS Angular file? I'm using a jQuery plug-in to generate some value. I want to connect this value to my $scope variable in my controller. However, this value is constantly changing, and I don't think my $scope variable auto-updates with changes to a non Angular variable. What's a good way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: no.. it wont.. I think one option you have is to use a interval based solution which has to update the scope variable with the global variable value

Comment: @ArunPJohny You can use the function form of $watch to achieve this. See my answer for details.

Comment: @metacubed then who will trigger the digest cycle when the value is changed...

Comment: @metacubed yes... the watch will get triggered during the next digest cycle triggered by some other action

Comment: What kind of plugin are you using? does the value bind to a certain element? or does it simply update a global variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `$watch` on the global variable by wrapping it in a function. Inside the controller's `link` function, add this:

```
$scope.$watch(
    function() {
        return globalVar;
    },
    function(newValue, oldValue) {
        // Global var changed! Do stuff.
        $scope.scopeVar = newValue;
    });
```

AngularJS keeps polling or checking for the return value of the first function, which returns your global variable. This is done multiple times per digest cycle.

When the value changes, it calls the second function, which is the event handler for the change. You can add logic for handling the change here. The change handler is passed in both the old and the new values for convenience.

In this case, I am simply setting a scope variable with the changed global value.

Comment: have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lfz8bo11/2/ - if you keep ideal nothing happens... but only when you click on the button the variable is updated

Comment: @ArunPJohny right.. there is nothing to trigger the digest otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If the global variable is updated outside of angujarjs, one possible solution is what is proposed by @metacubed but it has a problem that is if there is no digest cycles executed by other operations the variables will not get updated... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lfz8bo11/2/

So another solution I can propose is to use a interval based approach(It can be costly because of the constant executions of digest cycles) like

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.mycounter = counter;

  $interval(function() {
    $scope.mycounter = counter;
  }, 1000);

  $scope.something = function() {}
})

var counter = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  counter++;
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  {{mycounter}}
  <button ng-click="something()">Do something</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Dang, if it really is too costly, then perhaps I should just process my variable through the non-angular js file and have it display with jQuery....

Comment: If you have control over who is updating the value.... then you can think about a custom jQuery event and then you can use a directive

Comment: Now, I've got my jQuery way of doing it working. The value is just appending to a span. You're saying that I can use an angular directive to watch this span's content and update as this appended value is being changed (jquery empty+append)?

Comment: @pyramidface see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lfz8bo11/5/ - this won't trigger any unnecessary digest cycles

Answer (score 0):

The interval solution seems to work, but as @Arun-p-johny said, could have a lot of perfomance cost,

I suggest another aproach, working around: 'calling the digist cycle of the scope only when the variable changes'

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahpuser/Lfz8bo11/6/)

```
var updateDigest = function(){
    var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=my-app]');
    var appScope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
    var controllerScope = appScope.$$childHead;
    controllerScope.$digest();
};

var counter = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    counter++;
    updateDigest();
}, 500);
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570357/angularjs-access-controller-scope-from-outside)

This is working supposing the first child is the scope you are using.. ( in your app could not be the case ), so maybe a work around as getting the rootscope( [eg. jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahpuser/Lfz8bo11/8/) ) doing an emit or setting a variable in rootscope.

Or a better and elegant solution that I would recommend.. bring the external library to angular context ( create a wrapper ), seems for me the better solution.

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.mycounter = counter;

  $rootScope.$on('updateOuter', function(e, d) {
    console.log('d', d);
    $scope.mycounter = d;
    $scope.$apply();
  });

  $scope.something = function() {}
});

var updateDigest = function(param) {
  var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=my-app]');
  var appScope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
  var rootScope = appScope;
  rootScope.$emit('updateOuter', param);
};

var counter = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  counter++;
  updateDigest(counter);
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<body ng-app="my-app">
  <div id="container" ng-controller="AppController">
    {{mycounter}}
  </div>
</body>
```