# unable to get $scope value in partial view in mvc and angularjs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to load partial in my main. 
this my `_layout.cshtml` page.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Angular/Module.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
    @Ajax.ActionLink("IMR", "Demo", "IMR", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divBody" })
    <div class="container body-content" id="divBody">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

As I have ajax action link on my layout page, which call the Demo action of IMR controller.

```
 public ActionResult Demo()  
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

This is my **Demo partila view**.

```
<script src="~/Content/Angular/IMRController.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="mycntrl">
    {{myname}}
</div>
```

**Module.Js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp', []);
```

**IMRController.js**

```
myApp.controller("mycntrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.myname = "Amit";
});
```

But in demo.cshtml, I click on IMR , it render partial view, but it doesn't show the value of `myname`
It is showing expression in browser

```
{{myname}}
```

Comment: Not really sure about the asp side of things but first solution I would try is to trigger the angular $digest cycle after the ajax call by using $scope.$apply()

Comment: where I have to write `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: @Ajax.ActionLink("IMR", "Demo", "IMR", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divBody",  OnSuccess = "$scope.$apply()" })

Comment: $scope is not defined

Answer (score 1):

In you  angular controller create a a global function on the window:

```
window.update = function(){
 var scope = angular.element($("#div-where-ng-app-is")).scope();
    scope.$apply()
}
```

and in your asp control call the global function update() on Success:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("IMR", "Demo", "IMR", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divBody", OnSuccess = "window.update()" })
```

Comment: You need to access the $scope from window, something like this is similar to what you have to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570357/angularjs-access-controller-scope-from-outside