# Change controllers variable in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.names = [
    {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
    {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
    {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}
];
});

function abc(){
 $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
     $scope.names = result; // here
 }});
}
```

I want to change the content of scope.names by result(it will be in json format) and then render the contents through angular.

And i want to clarify that i am bound to use get request from inside a function, so cant use $http of angular

Comment: Don't use $.ajax, use $http

Comment: @entre Cant use $http

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22575672/3894168) might help.

Comment: What's the reason you can't use $http

Comment: @SahilJain could you look at mine answer

Comment: @entre The app was not fully built in angular, so i have to get data from pre built js functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you don't have access to the scope. You need to access scope in hacky way by using `angular.element('[ng-controller=namesCtrl]').scope()` then you would have actual control over scope, but the variable changes in a scope wouldn't run digest cycle, You need to run it manually by using `$apply()` on that scope.

**Code**

```
function abc(){
 $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
    var scope = angular.element('[ng-controller=namesCtrl]').scope()
    scope.names = result; // here
    if(!scope.$$phase)
      scope.$apply(); //this will make available names in namesCtrl scope.
 }});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$http` instead of ajax because `$http` takes care of running digest cycle which takes care of 2 way binding.

```
function abc(){
  $http.get("demo_test.txt")
  .then(function(result){
     $scope.names = result;
  });
}
```

If for whatever reason you cannot use `$http` then you have to call `$scope.$apply` method to set the scoped values because it internally runs the digest cycle.

```
function abc(){
 $.ajax({
    url: "demo_test.txt", 
    success: function(result){
      $scope.$apply(function () {
         $scope.names = result;
      });
    }
 });
}
```

If you have `abc` method outside of your controller then you will have to get the controller scope as shown below which however is not a recommended by angular.

```
function abc(){
 var $scope = angular.element('[ng-controller=namesCtrl]').scope();
 $.ajax({
    url: "demo_test.txt", 
    success: function(result){
      $scope.$apply(function () {
         $scope.names = result;
      });
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: And how does `abc` knows about `$scope`?

Comment: OP is already accessing $scope inside abc so I assume that it is in a closure.

Comment: @OP - how are you calling abc method?

Comment: I am sure what OP meant by `$scope.names = result; // here` is how will he access the scope outside the controller.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Good copy paste.. :p I already have `angular.element('[ng-controller=namesCtrl]').scope()` thing in my answer..

Comment: @pankajparkar: I was assuming OP has access to $scope in a closure. It wasn't a copy paste but one of the ways to get the scope which I am already aware of.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Okay..I just pointed that out..Any ways..now OP will accept your answer..because you added it first & updated the answer in correct way..meaning which will tends to accept your answer by OP.though it already has covered by another answer-er..

Comment: @ShankarSangoli I asked it from OP not from you..there might be a case sometime they forgot to do it..Are you saying that my answer is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You need something to let Angular know that it needs to watch for that change. The Angular way of doing this is with [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), but you can also use [$scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

Comment: Actually, i am a newbie to angular. So it wud be helpful if you can provide me a snippet