# How to clear one View's Input value from other View?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, angularjs

My scenario is so simple and straight forward. But I'm failing to get the exact output.

In my case, I'm having two html page named as, Index.htm, Main.htm and One script page named as mscript.js. Index.htm consists of one button (Clear) and Main.htm consists of one input type field as text.

**What I want is:**

On clicking of button(from Index view), the text entered  by the user in the input type field(from Main view) has to be cleared.

**What i tried is**

I have used configuration block.

**Index.htm:**

```
<div data-ng-app="mangular">
    <div data-ng-controller="mcontroller">Strictly for Demo Purpose
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div data-ng-view=""></div>
        <br />
        <button type="submit" data-ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Main.htm**

```
<div>
  Type your Name : 
  <input type = "text" data-ng-model = "demotext" />
</div>
```

**mscript.js**

```
 var mangular = angular.module('mangular', ['ngRoute']);

mangular.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'Main.htm'
    })
});

mangular.controller('mcontroller', function ($scope) {

    //var test = mfactory.getinput();
    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.demotext = ""; // This is the place where I'm expecting solution
    }
});
```

Comment: See this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570357/angularjs-access-controller-scope-from-outside)

Comment: @gkrishy.  try to declare demotext in mcontroller:

Answer (score 1):

Use `$broadcast`, a built-in service of angularjs. On first page button click broadcast something and in your second page receive the broadcasted event and clear the data on input element.

from `mcontroller`

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("cleardata", anyObject);  // here you are broadcasting some data which is identified the a name/key that is for this example 'cleardata'
```

in the controller of ***Main.htm***

```
$rootScope.$on("cleardata", function (event, objectData) {
    // do whatever you want and clear the textbox
});
```

Comment: $broadcast is a good way. Can you explain with code as I'm not aware of it ?

Comment: @gkrishy, you can have an idea out of the provided code.

Comment: I got your point. Will this work for my scenario ? If so where you want me to put this line of code "$rootScope.$broadcast("cleardata", anyObject);" ?. And I'm having only one button click event and only one controller I'm using, other than this I'm not going anywhere to get data. I want to call directly the input field.

Comment: You have two views and if both of those have individual controllers then for `Index.htm` view, put `$rootScope.$broadcast("cleardata", anyObject);` inside the click event handler. And the `$rootScope.$on` part on the controller of `Main.htm` view. No need to put it inside any click or other event handler. So this way should work.

Comment: anyObject in the sense ?. And shall i clear the textbox like this $scope.demotext = ""; ?

Comment: if you want to pass any data then you can do that. else don't pass. simply broadcast with a msg/name, no object. you may have a look at here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope . search for $broadcast

Comment: Am i able to clear the textbox like this $scope.demotext = ""; within $rootScope.$on ?

Comment: yes indeed. as $on will be handler whenever you'll $broadcast after a button click. so you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/Mh2UH/31/

But, 
- I added controller to `$routeProvider.

- And inside, I added `$scope.$watch`.

then it works

```
var myApp = angular
    .module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                template: '<div>Type your Name : <input type = "text" ng-model = "text" /></div>',
                controller: 'viewCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    })
```

...

```
myApp.factory('aProvider', function () {
    return {
        text: "default Text"
    }
});
```

...

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, aProvider) {
    $scope.clear = function () {
        aProvider.text = "";
    }
});

myApp.controller('viewCtrl', function ($scope, aProvider) {
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return aProvider.text;
    }, function (val) {
        $scope.text = val;
    })

    $scope.$watch('text', function (val) {
        aProvider.text = val;
    })
});
```

Comment: @gkrishy. sorry, i forgot ngView is directive. i thought that main.htm's scope parent is index.html. I also updated

Comment: Really great. +1 for alternative way(template in config). But my exact requirement is for two views. I want to clear the input value from one view on clicking of button from other view.

Comment: Thanks, for your great question. +1

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller for Main.html, for example `mainctrl`, and from `mcontroller` access it like this `$scope.$parent.mainctrl.demotext = "";`

Comment: Ah right, yoy need a parent controller for them, maybe that's what you should do if it fits your app. It's a great and easy way of sharing info and functions between child controllers.