# AngularJS: Share data between different controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, scope

I have the following structures

```
<div ng-controller='ctrlA'>
  <button ng-click='updateFactoryData(data)'></button>

  <custom-dir>Custom directive with ctrlB</custom-dir>
  <custom-dir>Custom directive with ctrlB</custom-dir>
  <custom-dir>Custom directive with ctrlB</custom-dir>
  ...
  <other-custom-dir>Custom directive with ctrlC</other-custom-dir>
  <other-custom-dir>Custom directive with ctrlC</other-custom-dir>
  <other-custom-dir>Custom directive with ctrlC</other-custom-dir>
  ...
</div>
```

I have a dataFactory, which when user clicks the button, the updated data will store in dataFactory, the dataFactory is injected to both ctrlB and ctrlC.

The problem is, when data is updated after clicking the button, the changes do not reflect on both custom-dir and other-custom-dir, is there any way ctrlB and ctrlC's scope value automatically reflect the changes made in scope under ctrlA?

Thanks very much for the help!

Thanks all for the kind help!! I finally figure out why the change cannot be reflected, I watch the object parameter to see if there are changes, but watch only monitor the object reference instead of the actual content, after deep watching the object parameter, I can finally get the watch work! Thanks for all the help

```
<custom-dir para="{data: data}"></custom-dir>
```

Then in directive's link function

```
scope.$watch('para.data', function(n,o){
                alert('changed')
            }, true); //>> The true is important!!
```

Comment: can you share angular code ?

Comment: you need to watch on variable in directive link function,so that link function will get executed where watch function detect any changes on variable refer http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2658-using-scope-watch-to-watch-functions-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: There are many ways to do this. What have you tried?

Comment: I can suggest few things: you can try to use `rootScope`, you can inject scope variables by attributes, you can use `$digest || $apply` on data changing, also you can represent scope as `angular.service` and give to any scope even isolated as you have. But more likely you have to change your architecture. Also on such a questions pls let us a fiddle or whatever with live code.

Comment: try with watch(http://stackoverflow.com/a/32350012/4365315) or (http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/Mh2UH/31/)

Answer (score 0):

- Pass the value to attribute in the `<custom-dir>` and `<other-custom-dir>`

  `<custom-dir data="data">`  `</custom-dir>`
- Observe the change from the directive

  ```
  attrs.$observe('data', function(value){
     // call your directive controller here ...
  })
  ```

**The Benefit :**

By passing data from attribute, the directive do not have to know about the controller/the source of the data, so, this reduce dependecy.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you need to share scope is a bit weird knowing that you have a parent controller that can contain your $scope item

Answer (score 0):

It's considered a best practice to use "controllerAs" and no longer use `$scope`.

By writing:

```
<div ng-controller='ctrlA as a'>
    <button ng-click='a.updateFactoryData(data)'></button>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

and:

```
function ctrlA () {
    this.data = [];
    this.updateFactoryData = function (data) {
        //...
    }
}
```

You access your controller's data with `a.data` everywhere inside your `div`.

Answer (score -1):

Basically what you require is here is share the factory data changes in your directives. So you can bind your desired factory data using different approaches based on your requirements(i.e. @ attribute,= 2 way model, & expression bindings) in directives and than watch those variables in directives link functions (i.e. ideal place where you needs to handle those watch conditions) for changes so once anything will update on factory (through button click), it will automatically propagated in your directives. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/maxisam/QrCXh/) is the example to do different bindings.

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
.directive('myComponent', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
            /* NOTE: Normally I would set my attributes and bindings
            to be the same name but I wanted to delineate between 
            parent and isolated scope. */                
            isolatedAttributeFoo:'@attributeFoo',
            isolatedBindingFoo:'=bindingFoo',
            isolatedExpressionFoo:'&'
        }        
    };
})


<my-component attribute-foo="{{foo}}" binding-foo="foo" 
isolated-expression-foo="updateFoo(newFoo)" >
    <h2>Attribute</h2>
    <div>
        <strong>set:</strong> <input ng-model="isolatedAttributeFoo">
        <i>// This does not update the parent scope.</i>
    </div>
    <h2>Binding</h2>
    <div>
        <strong>get:</strong> {{isolatedBindingFoo}}
    </div>
    <h2>Expression</h2>    
    <div>
        <input ng-model="isolatedFoo">
        <button class="btn" ng-click="isolatedExpressionFoo({newFoo:isolatedFoo})">
            Submit</button>
        <i>// And this calls a function on the parent scope.</i>
    </div>
</my-component>
```

I have made sample demo to illustrate the approach please check [this](http://embed.plnkr.co/DcBE1x/).

Comment: @Downvoters Please specify the reason why downvoted so it helps me to identify the missing bridge if there is any from my end..