# Automatically changing an input field on change without access to $scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I've been looking and trying to work on this for a while, but the way my company does things causes it to be unnecessarily difficult for me.  At work I do a lot of work on an internal customer facing system that we edit entirely in HTML using AngularJS.  We can run scripts locally in these HTML files but can not access the $scope in our functions.

I have an input field as shown below, and I need it to limit the phone number to 10 digits and automatically remove any non-numerical value.  What I'm doing so far is this.

At the beginning of the HTML file, the scripting:

```html
<script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">
 fixPhoneNumber = function(interviewProperty) {
     var cleaned = iData[interviewProperty]
     cleaned = cleaned.replace(/\D/g,'');
         iData[interviewProperty] = cleaned;
     console.log(testing testing testing);
 }
</script>
```

and in the data itself, this is how I'm attempting to call the data.  I'll answer any questions if I'm not specific enough, but I think I've gotten everything shown here.

```html
<button id="copyDP" class="copyButton" ng-click="copy_cust_data('phone', 'local_dir_ad_phone');" type="button">Copy Customer Phone</button><br/>
<input id="local_dir_ad_phone" type="text" class="k-textbox spellcheck" style="width:100%;" ng-change="fixPhoneNumber('local_dir_ad_phone')" ng-required="iData.site_addr_phone_same==='YES'"  ng-model="iData.local_dir_ad_phone" /><br/>
<span class="error" ng-show="(iData.local_dir_ad_phone==undefined) || (iData.local_dir_ad_phone==='')">This information is required.</span>
<br/>
<ul>
 <li>Is this also the best number for us to reach you at?
  <ul>
   <input id="contact_phone_good" type="radio" ng-model="iData.contact_phone_good" value="YES" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Yes</b><br/>
   <input id="contact_phone_good" type="radio" ng-model="iData.contact_phone_good" value="NO" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>No</b><br/>
   <div ng-show="iData.contact_phone_good==='NO'">
    <ul>
     <li>What is the best number for us to reach you at? <span id="usernote">(Update Prospector Customer record with best contact number)</span></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

The value I'm looking to have changed is the 'local_dir_ad_phone' as it already has the ng-change applied in this example.  Is there perhaps some reason that ng-change wouldn't actually execute its function every time a change was made?  From reading the API, I'm under the impression that it should run it on every change made real time.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: is it not executing or are you changes not applied?

Comment: all changes to the code are hitting the server but it's not executing, I can type letters in freely and it doesn't override them or remove them.

Comment: but the console.log line fires. you can access scope through a directive, if you can add that.

Comment: Can't you limit the number of digits using maxlength="10"?

Comment: @Jorg the console.log line doesn't fire.  That's a relic that I hadn't commented out.  It was to test that very thing, whether I could access the scope.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570357/angularjs-access-controller-scope-from-outside)... it shows how to access scope by selecting the right elements.

Comment: Thanks @Jorg I'll work with this and reply back with anything I get from it.  It looks interesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying-

You are changing the value of the input outside of angular so it's not seeing the change. If you are changing input outside of angular you need to call `$scope.$apply()` to apply you changes. Since you don't have access to scope you can do it by calling `$apply` on `$rootScope`.

```
angular.element('body').injector().get('$rootScope').$apply();
```

But this sucks and you should talk to someone at work about getting a handle on the scope as this would cause a digest for the entire app.

Comment: Thanks!  This is the closest I'll get for now.  We're an older company with huge bureaucracy surrounding the code of the disparate systems that we're trying to patch together to work on our platform as we need. Given enough time, I can get a directive put on the scope, but until then I'll be working around the problems to attempt to do my job