# Scope is not getting created for dynamically loaded for external angularjs file

Tags: angularjs

```
    <script>
        jQuery.loadScript = function (url, callback) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'script',
                success: callback,
                async: true
           });
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.loadScript('../Scripts/MyController.js', function(){
                var ScopeReport = angular.element($('[ng-controller=MyController]')).scope();
            })
        })
    </script>
```

I created a external file with name MyController.js which has an `angularjs` controller with name MyController.
I tried to load dynamically. But I am unable to access the scope of the dynamically loaded angular controller.

Comment: I doubt if it is possible to load a controller's scope this way. jQuery would not have any idea about the angular life-cycle. In the ideal case, you would be accessing `ScopeReport` inside an already initialized controller. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570357/angularjs-access-controller-scope-from-outside)

Comment: How are you bootstrapping the AngularJS app? You need to make sure that the app bootstraps after the controller is loaded. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).